# Apply jQuery Events After AJAX Load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a range of events dynamically added to hyperlinks using jQuery selectors...

EG...

```
$('a[data-toggle="email"]').click(function(){
//Do Something
});
```

The issue I have is that I have a number of div's which are populated using AJAX due to long render times which can also have data toggles in them which I need to be able to attach the same events to, however the events don't attach.

I have tried manually calling my `init();` method which contains all of the jQuery initiators but it adds the same events to previously altered dom objects a second time which throws a wide range of UI and workflow glitches.

My question is if there is a way to only allow the jQuery initiators to make changes to DOM objects which have not already had the changes made to them or if there is a better way to do this. The point of doing it this way is to eliminate the need to duplicate code into multiple places or to need to manually call the methods after every single AJAX load or in multiple places, so a jQuery native solution which will automatically apply the alterations after an AJAX load is completed only to the newly loaded content would be prefered. All AJAX loads are done into a base DIV with the DIV itself being defined as the parent object using the `jQuery.load()` method.

My current code is as follows...

jQuery Initiators

```
function jInit() {
    /*
     * The following selectors and methods are executed when the page finishes loading and are used to automatically apply jQuery based functionality to pre-defined dom objects.
     */

    //Automatically close displayed message callouts after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){$(".callout").hide("drop"); }, 3000);

    //Enable contact name links to display modal contact card
    $('a[data-toggle="contact-card"]').click(function(){
        alert('Show contact card!');
    });

    //Configure all email links to be sent using CCB email activity form
    $('a[data-toggle="email"]').click(function(){
        alert("Send email to " + $(this).text() + " using CCB email activity");
    });

    //Configure all help buttons to trigger help sidebar
    $('a[data-toggle="help"]').click(function(){
        alert("Show help file " + $(this).data("help-file"));
    });

    //Configure all user links to show user overview hovercard
    $('a[data-toggle="user"]').hovercard({
         detailsHTML: 'Loading...',
         width: 400,
         onHoverIn: function() {
             var elem = $(this).children("div");
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/components/users/_hovercards/user-hovercard.php',
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 beforeSend: function() {
                     elem.html("Loading...");
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                     elem.empty();
                     elem.html(data);
                 },
                 complete: function() {

                 },
                 error: function() {
                     elem.html("An error occured loading the user data...");
                 }
             });
         }
    });
};
```

The parent DIV which loads content using AJAX...

```
<div class="box-body no-padding" data-toggle="pagelet" data-url="/components/activities/_pagelets/activities.pagelet.php?filter=account&amp;rid=934793475934953&amp;latest=10">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

NB: The pagelet initiator looks like this...

```
$('[data-toggle="pagelet"]').each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("url"), function(response, status, xhr) {
            if(status == "error") {
                $(this).html("<div class='text-center'>An error occured loading the pagelet<br />" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "</div>");
                return false;
            };
        });
    });
```

Any assistance with this is appreciated.

Comment: See *[jQuery event delgation using .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)*

Comment: Thanks @ShaunakD, wasn't exactly what I needed but did put me on the right path to get it in the end, have posted the solution that I was able to work out with context selectors below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the way to do this, further research into the jQuery selector showed me that I could apply an optional context parameter to the selector would limit the scope of the selector to child elements of the defined context.

With this what I was able to do was add the `jInit();` method to the `.load()` module on success and force it to run but define the context parameter as `jInit(this);` and take the parameter and embed it in every selector within the `jInit();` method. For the initial method execution on page load I define the context as `jInit(document);`.

EG...

```
function jInit(context) {
    /*
     * The following selectors and methods are executed when the page finishes loading and are used to automatically apply jQuery based functionality to pre-defined dom objects.
     */

    //Automatically close displayed message callouts after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){$(".callout", context).hide("drop"); }, 3000);

    $(".test1", context).html("TEst Success");

    //Enable contact name links to display modal contact card
    $('a[data-toggle="contact-card"]', context).click(function(){
        alert('Show contact card!');
    });

    //Configure all email links to be sent using CCB email activity form
    $('a[data-toggle="email"]', context).click(function(){
        alert("Send email to " + $(this).text() + " using CCB email activity");
    });

    //Configure all help buttons to trigger help sidebar
    $('a[data-toggle="help"]', context).click(function(){
        alert("Show help file " + $(this).data("help-file"));
    });

    //Configure all user links to show user overview hovercard
    $('a[data-toggle="user"]', context).hovercard({
         detailsHTML: 'Loading...',
         width: 400,
         onHoverIn: function() {
             var elem = $(this).children("div");
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/components/users/_hovercards/user-hovercard.php',
                 type: 'GET',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 beforeSend: function() {
                     elem.html("Loading...");
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                     elem.empty();
                     elem.html(data);
                 },
                 complete: function() {

                 },
                 error: function() {
                     elem.html("An error occured loading the user data...");
                 }
             });
         }
    });
};
```

And the AJAX loader...

```
$(this).load($(this).data("url"), function(response, status, xhr) {
            if(status == "error") {
                $(this).html("<div class='text-center'>An error occured loading the pagelet<br />" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "</div>");
                return false;
            } else {
                //Load Was Successful
                jInit(this);
            };
        });
```

And finally the initial initiator on page load...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jInit(document);
});
```